# Eliminate leading/trailing spaces around punctuation marks

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I've got a textfield with a bunch of punctuation which is always surrounded by spaces. So that for instance:

```
I don't recall saying ' pick up the boot ' or ' now is the time ' . But it's possible , so I may have .
```

What is the regular expression syntax to get rid of these spaces? I'm working in actionscript.

Edit: it's actually both leading and trailing, as you can see from the above example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var str:String = "I don't recall saying ' pick up the boot ' or ' now is the time ' . But it's possible , so I may have .";

// "foo ' bar ' baz" => "foo 'bar' baz"
var re1:RegExp = /'\s(.*?)\s'/g;
str = str.replace(re1, "'$1'");

// "foo , bar . baz" => "foo, bar. baz"
var re2:RegExp = /\s([.,])/g;
str = str.replace(re2, "$1");
```

For this particular string you'll get that result:

```
I don't recall saying 'pick up the boot' or 'now is the time'. But it's possible, so I may have.
```

May be the first regexp need some adjustments as it won't work for string like

```
I didn ' t say ' foo '.
```

as it'll be converted to

```
I didn 't say' foo '.
```

Short explanation for special symbols used in first regexp:

- `\s` is for space character (space, tab)
- `.` means any character
- `*` zero or more repetition
- `?` makes `*` quantifier non-greedy, so it'll match as less characters as possible
- wrapping it all in parenthesis creates a capturing group; we can later refer its content in replacement string as `$1`

You can find more information about regexps on [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) or in [this section](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ea9.html) of docs from Adobe.

Comment: Thanks! How would you write that first re1 in English? Would it be: re1 is a pattern which will find singlequote followed by ...? The part I'm having the most trouble understanding is (.*?)  Also in the replace, what exactly is "'$1'" doing?

Comment: I added short explanations, but if you're going to use regexp in your code you better read a bit about them.

Comment: Yes, have been reading up on them, but your explanation makes the going faster. Thanks again.